# strange "word has no context" error in rebol program

Tags: bind, rebol

Here is my error from the console:

```
>> ? column
COLUMN is a block of value: [Person 2 Date 3 Quantity 4 Size 5 ProductType 6 
LineItem  7 Deliver 8 FillStatus 9 Note 10 Time 11]
>> ? column/Size
COLUMN/SIZE is an integer of value: 5
>> ? a
A is a block of value: [column/Size]
>> reduce a
** Script Error: column word has no context
** Near: column/Size
>> ? b
B is a block of value: [column/Size]
>> reduce b
== [5]
```

Why doesn't the variable 'a' reduce properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you defined  `column` and `a` because when I try it from console, it works:

```
>> column: [Person 2 Date 3 Quantity 4 Size 5 ProductType 6 LineItem  7 Deliver 8 FillStatus 9 Note 10 Time 11]
== [Person 2 Date 3 Quantity 4 Size 5 ProductType 6 LineItem 7 Deliver 8 FillStatus 9 Note 10 Time 11]

>> a: [column/size]
== [column/size]

>> reduce a
== [5]
```

Anyway, you can try binding `a`:

```
>> reduce bind a 'column
== [5]
```

Comment: That is the correct answer. The gotcha was that 'a' was bound in a previously run function to a different context. My Bad.